# IE 8 Not Rendering SoundCloud Flash Player

Tags: internet-explorer, soundcloud

**Goal:** to create a custom audio player using the custom player files from SoundCloud (http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/custom-player).

**Problem:** IE does not render the "backup" flash player in IE8 (and lower). I would like to avoid flash all together. The player is located here: http://ryanwieseler.com/tpmwordpress

IE 8 gives an error stemming from the use of "addEventListener" instead of the "attachEvent" in the sc-player.js. I have limited knowledge of JavaScript so here's a **another question**: would the issue be solved by amending the sc-player.js with a function found in the answer in this thread: http://goo.gl/bYFge? Identify which method a browser can use and implement it? sc-player.js via github (https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-custom-player/blob/master/js/sc-player.js)

Any suggestions are much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you execute this before sc-player.js, it might work:

```
if (!soundcloud.addEventListener) {
    soundcloud.addEventListener = function(eventName, eventHandler) {
      this.attachEvent('on' + eventName, eventHandler);
    }
}
```